# Why not create a battery manager?

Tags: battery

Why not create a battery manager? The battery with the elementary lasts half as long as with Windows 10. create a battery manager like Windows, to save battery ... would be the first linux to do thiss.

Comment: there are 3rd-party tools for this already, however their performence is too much hardware dependent to be shipped by default

Comment: Install this apps and learn to use them. Then you'll have better battery life. `sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw powertop`